# Linux : Copy and replace directory with its files

Tags: linux, shell

I have a folder which i want to copy and overwrite an existing folder in a directory.
Logic : i unzip the file , it will consist of 3 files [ test1.txt, test2.txt, test3.txt ]

```
Source Folder
- home/source/folder1
  - test.zip

Targer Folder
- home/target
```

when i use the unzip command , file structure will be as follow

```
- home/target/folder1
  - test1.txt
  - test2.txt
  - test3.txt
  - test.zip
```

Initially i was using this command to copy the source folder to the target folder
cp -R  home/source/folder1 home/target

However, when i trigger this the second time , it will create a sub folder of folder1

```
- home/target/folder
  -test1.txt
  -test2.txt
  -test3.txt
  -test.zip
  -folder1
```

I found a few thread suggesting to use  -T command
cp -R -T home/source/folder1 home/target

However this will also result the same folder structure as

```
- home/target/folder
  -test1.txt
  -test2.txt
  -test3.txt
  -test.zip
  -folder1
```

The last resort which i will go to is to write a script to remove first and copy the folder

```
-rm -r home/target/folder
-cp -R home/source/folder1
```

Point 1 :

i was wondering if it is possible to replace or overwrite the whole folder itself
e.g after we have unzip the files , folder structure will be as this in target folder

```
- home/target/folder1
  -test1.txt
  -test2.txt
  -test3.txt
  -folder1
```

using the cp copy, it will automatically replace the existing folder1 and its content to how it is reflected in source folder

```
Source Folder
- home/target/folder1
  - test.zip
```

Using this approach is working as expected, however i was wondering if in point a approach is possible

```
[ -d  home/target/folder1 ] && echo "Workbook Directory Exist , removing twbx files content" && rm -r home/target/folder1
cp home/source/folder1 home/target
```

Comment: Looks like you want to sync folders, so I suggest you to use "rsync" command instead "cp".  For example:  "rsync -avz home/source/folder1 /home/target"